# How to pass the Database connection Url, port, username and password in Cypress.io using the task method?

Tags: cypress

How to pass Database connection Url, port, username and password in Cypress.io using the task method. I would like to get table values from MySQL database. Can someone please advise how to get the table values ?

```
cy.task(event, arg, options)
```

Comment: See this example [Testing the database](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/powerful-cy-task/#testing-the-database).

Comment: @Eric99- Will check that, thanks

Comment: @eric99: In this link where do we give the database name, username, password, `const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const repoRoot = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..')'

Comment: I haven't studied it too much, but off the top of my head - `cypress/plugins/index.js` is the code that runs in the Node env, so that is where you access the db. Simplest to hard code those items (or `fs.read` them from a file), but also `cy.task()` takes an args param where you could pass them in.

Comment: @eric99 Thanks, if I get to it successfully, will share that here

Comment: That will be interesting. BTW, another approach might be to create an API for db related functions in your app and expose it to Cypress by adding it to `window` upon app start. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068995/how-to-expose-access-a-data-store-like-redux-within-a-cypress-test) which shows how to expose Redux.

Comment: Ok, will look that too