# How to expose/access a data store state within a cypress test in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, ngrx-store

I'm trying to create some Cypress tests for an Angular 7 application which uses ngrx-store.  I was hoping to pre-load some data into the store in order to then test the UI.  Unfortunately I am not sure how to directly load the required data into the store, without using a dispatch.

I have managed to expose the store, as described in this example ([How to expose/access a data store like Redux within a cypress test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068995/how-to-expose-access-a-data-store-like-redux-within-a-cypress-test)) however I would like to manipulate the state directly without dispatching an action.  My guess is I somehow need to set a test-specific initial state for the store/state

Here's what I did so far:

```
    // in app.component
    if (window.Cypress) {
                // @ts-ignore
                window.__appStore__ = store$;
            }

    // in the test
    cy.window().then(w => {
            console.log(w.__appStore__);
    }
```

The above  works fine. I get the store, but can only manipulate it through its API.  What I really want is the state of the the store to manipulate it directly.

Comment: constructor(
    public employeesService: EmployeesFacade,
    public federalTaxesService: FederalTaxesFacade,
    public stateTaxesService: StateTaxesFacade,
    public stateW4Service: StateW4Facade
  ) {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (window.Cypress) {
     
      window.EmployeesFacadeStore = this.employeesService;
    }
  }

Comment: I used the code above in a component.

Comment: beforeEach(function() {
      cy.window().then(w => {
        w.EmployeesFacadeStore.updateEmployee('accountId', 'uuid', employee);
      });
    });

Comment: I used the code above in my cypress test

Comment: @user372225, can you please remove your comments and instead place them in an actual answer, with formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating redux state directly - goes against the state immutability methodology. My assumption is that you probably shouldn't be mutating state directly unless there's another reason.
https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/store

If you are performing e2e tests, then act on the user-interface elements and assert changes to the UI state. Whatever NGRX does behind the scenes is out of scope for this type of test.
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/11/14/testing-redux-store/#drive-using-the-dom

For this you're going to want to use `cy.session()`.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Where-to-call-cy-session

Sessions allow you to save "the current state" of localStorage to be reused across your tests. Just make sure that your localStorage objects have completely populated when you create your cy.session().

Adding the `validate` block will help you make sure the session is in a good state before starting your tests.